# SOLVED C# HttpWebResponse delivers different response than Postman

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse

I'm consuming a Web API of an internal system in the company.
It's getting a payload in JSON format and returning a response with data in JSON format.
When sending the request with Postman, it returns the expected response (StatusCode=200 + a response text in JSON format). That means that everything is OK with the web service.

Now I have to develop an application in C# to send this HTTP request.
The problem is, that I receive as response content "OK" and not the expected JSON response gotten with Postman.

```
    public HttpWebResponse SendRequest(string url, string checkOutFolder, string drawingNo, string login, string password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        string payload = GeneratePayLoad(checkOutFolder, drawingNo);
        string header = CreateAuthorization(login, password);

        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = header;
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

        var type = request.GetType();
        var currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(request);

        var methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
        methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(payload);
        }

        // Response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseContent = rd.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Has anyone already experiences something similar.
Can you help me?

**EDIT**
Following your suggestions
1) Changed the method to POST -> result is still the same
2) Used Postman's code generator and RestSharp -> result is still the same

```
        public void Request(string url, string checkOutFolder, string drawingNo, string login, string password)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.Post;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic **********");
        var body = GeneratePayLoad(checkOutFolder, drawingNo);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

3. Changed to HttpClient -> result still the same

   ```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string uri = "******************";
            string path = "destinationpath";
            var endpoint = new Uri(uri);
            string payload = GeneratePayLoad(path, "100-0000947591");
            //FormUrlEncodedContent form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(payload);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(payload);
            var payload2 = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("*******");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization.ToString()));
            var result = client.PostAsync(endpoint, stringContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
   ```

   4. Wrote a Python code using requests Package -> delivers the same as Postman. So the problem is in the C# code.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

**SOLVED**
The issue was on the payload generation!

Comment: Use [Postman's code generator](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/) to get the raw HTTP for your request and add it to your question. That will likely show us what is wrong with your code.

Comment: What is the difference you notice between the response in postman and code?

Comment: Web request is outdated, don't expect very much from it. Use httpclient.

Comment: The expected content is a JSON responde with more than 1000 characters. I get it on Postman and using Python (requests). I changed the method to Post and also wrote a function using HttpClient. I still get the same result.

Comment: @Daniel Can you please show us the Postman request? You can generate the Postman request's code (there are many options, any of them will do). You can share that with us or just look at it for clues.

Or at least post a screenshot of the Postman UI so we'll see the request that works

Comment: @Mzn I just copied some screenshots. The generated code is the one using RestSharp (code on attemp no 2). The only difference is to create the response. Postman uses IRestResponse, but this is no longer available in RestSharp, so I replace it with RestSharp.RestResponse.

Comment: `payload2` is the correct way to create json string content. Try sending that instead of `stringContent`. It would be helpful if you didn't put unused lines of code in your example. We also can't see what `GeneratePayLoad` is doing so there could be a problem there.

Comment: The problem was on the payload generation!

Answer (score 1):

The request needs to be an HTTP POST and not HTTP GET because it contains JSON payload.

`request.Method = "GET";` should be `request.Method = "POST";`

That would be one of the issue(s). I am not sure if there is something else that is wrong, but try changing the request method to POST and try again.

Comment: I think you are right, but technically you can send a body with GET. And, there are other methods that have content like PUT and PATCH so you can't say it *needs to be* POST.

Comment: @Crowcoder I see now, I agree, thank you. OP please note that you are probably not hitting the correct API when you use GET (despite the fact the GET can have a JSON body).

Comment: I changed the method to POST and still get the same result. I also tried using HttpClient and the result is exactly the same. The third try was using RestSharp (Postman's code generator), the response is also "OK" instead of a 1000-character JSON response.

Comment: @Daniel Will you please show us the request that works in Postman (generated code or screenshot)?